# Need algorithm for removing created duplicates

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a program I need to write, and I'm not sure how to do it. I need a reference to a method of how to solve it. The problem is as follows: 
You have a list of **N** integer numbers. For instance: **[4;2;3;2;1;5;1;3;2]**. 
If there is some **K** or higher number of adjacent duplicate numbers, they are removed from the list. You can add any number between any two numbers, or to the beginning/ending of the list, so that the numbers are removed from the list.

The task is to clear the list using as low amount of numbers as possible.

1 <= **N** <= 100 - **N** is the length of the list. 
2 <= **K** <= 5 - **K** is the minimum amount of duplicate adjacent numbers that are removed from the sequence.

**K** is provided in the ranges specified.

Example:
List = **[4;2;3;2;1;5;1;3;2]** - Answer is **3**; ***K*** = 2

My idea is to have some kind of sequence tree, so as to remove the numbers efficiently.
The tree for this example would look like:

```
4 2       2
   3     3
    2 1 1
       5
```

So you have to add **5** between 4th and 5th element of the list (starting from 0), then 4th to 7th elements disappear, and the sequence looks like this.

```
4 2   2
   3 3
    2
```

Now you add **2** between 2nd and 3rd element of the new sequence, so 1st to 5th elements are removed.

Then you add 4 to a new sequence, and the total amount of numbers added to the sequence was **3**. What is the algorithm to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't follow how the value of `K` is determined, and what you mean by _the answer is `3*K*=2`.

Comment: How would you build your tree?

Comment: @jogojapan Sorry, that was a typing mistake in editor.

Comment: @alestanis K is readed through file, so it is provided in the ranges specified.

Answer (score 0):

Let us reverse engineer the problem. Considering your example, the final string that can be reduced in on go will look like this

```
4           4
 2         2
  3       3
   2     2
    1   1
     5 5
```

and if you notice it is a palindrome of even length. And similar will be the case for all other inputs possible.

Now the problem can be reduced to finding the longest palindromic sub-sequence in the input and add a character to the input string corresponding to every character in the input which is not in the palindromic sub-sequence. Finding a longest palindromic sub-sequence is a standard DP problem and a tutorial can be found [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/19155)

For example in your case the longest sub-sequence would be `[2,3,1,1,3,2]` and the characters not in the input are `[4,2,5]` so you have to add these to the input or if you are interested in the number then `3` will be the answer.

Comment: OK, thank you, this does look promising. Now the question, is this DP method also possible when searching for sub-sequences of more than 2 2 surrounding elements. What I want to say, that K does not have to be 2. It can also be 3 or 4 or 5.

Comment: My bad. Didn't consider that part. Will think of it.